# Only layout page picking up CSS file (flask)

Tags: python, flask

My layout HTML file seems to be picking up the CSS right up until the `{% block ... %}`. The content in the block downwards doesn't pick up any CSS which means the pages that extend the layout page don't pickup any CSS. They all share the same CSS file.

**App structure**

```
run.py
/MyPortfolio
   /static
       styles.css
   /templates
       layout.html
       index.html
   __init.py
   views.py
```

**Layout.html**

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
<!-- picks  up CSS-->
<nav>...</nav>

<!-- doesn't pick up CSS downward-->

{% block body %} {% endblock %}

<div class="page-footer">
    ...
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: the stuff inside the block body, does the CSS inside those pages reference url_for('static')? 

All references to JS and CSS need to have url_for, regardless of how they are inserted

Comment: Apparently I have to clear my browser cache before restarting the app. It was linking the CSS not just updating it :(. Thanks for the help btw